# I want to upload an image from JSP page using BufferedOutputStream but object is not getting created an object of BOS

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping("/addImageAdmin")
public String addImageAdmin(@RequestParam("fname") String fname, @RequestParam("imgupload") MultipartFile file, ModelMap model) {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            ImageUpload du = new ImageUpload();
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

            // Creating the directory to store file
            String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
            File dir = new File("Important" + File.separator);
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            // Create the file on server
            File serverFile1 = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator);
            System.out.println("Before Stream");
            BufferedOutputStream stream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(serverFile1));
            System.out.println("After Stream");
            stream1.write(bytes);
            stream1.close();
            du.setFname(fname);
            du.setImgupload(bytes);

            if (imageUploadSerImpl.saveImage(du)) {
                model.addAttribute("msg", "1");
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("msg", "0");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

    }

    return "add/photogal";
}
```

Because of not creating an object of BufferedOutputStream save method is not getting called.. Please suggest.

Comment: Try one of these options - [Image in @RequestParam("imageFile")](https://github.com/RawSanj/spring-tiles-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sanjay/springtiles/controller/UserController.java#L48) or [Image in @ModelAttribute](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/blob/master/JamiaNew/src/main/java/in/jmi/controller/StudentController.java#L86).